# 128 character limit in UI test Xcode

Tags: ios, xctest, xcuitest

This test in failing because

> exceeds maximum length of 128 characters. You can work around this
>   limitation by constructing a query with a custom NSPredicate that
>   specifies the property (label, title, value, placeholderValue, or
>   identifier) to match against.'

```
func testMessage() {
        app.buttons["BEGIN"].tap()

        let tablesQuery = app.tables
        XCTAssert(tablesQuery.children(matching: .cell).element(boundBy: 0).staticTexts["<EXTREMELY LONG TEXT HERE (200chars)>"].exists)
    }
```

How could I convert this so that I could work around the 128 char limit while testing the validity of the text.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can use `label LIKE` for your full string:

```
let yourSuperLongText = "your super long string"
let predicate = NSPredicate(format: "label LIKE %@", yourSuperLongText)
let element = tablesQuery.children(matching: .cell).element(boundBy: 0).staticTexts.element(matching: predicate)

XCTAssert(element.exists)
```

Or you can use `label CONTAINS` for part of your string:

```
 let partOfYoursSuperLongText = "part of your super long string"
 let predicate = NSPredicate(format: "label CONTAINS[c] %@", partOfYoursSuperLongText)
 let element = tablesQuery.children(matching: .cell).element(boundBy: 0).staticTexts.element(matching: predicate)

 XCTAssert(element.exists)
```

More here: 
[How to test that staticTexts contains a string using XCTest](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38044374/how-to-test-that-statictexts-contains-a-string-using-xctest)

and here: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nspredicate

Comment: this is a nice solution for the 128 character limitation on UITests too